# How to make ListView always scroll to top?

Tags: android

My cutom List View:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class OverScrollView extends ListView {

    public OverScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public OverScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public OverScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private static int maxOverscroll = 200; 

    @Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(final int deltaX, final int deltaY, final int scrollX, final int scrollY, final int scrollRangeX, final int scrollRangeY, final int maxOverScrollX, final int maxOverScrollY, final boolean isTouchEvent) {
        return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, maxOverscroll, isTouchEvent);
    }

    private void init() {
        //maxOverscroll = (int) getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/3;
    }

}
```

It is custom `ListView` which is bouncing, the only problem is when Istop the scolling and wait 1 second the release the screen, the whole list view stands still and wont scroll up, or down. How can I make it to scroll to the top or bottom every time it is realesed.

my XML:

```
<sk.zp.overscroll.scrollView.OverScrollView
    android:id="@+id/list_senders"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/senders_label"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:overScrollMode="always" >
</sk.zp.overscroll.scrollView.OverScrollView>
```

Comment: Where did u place the code lstView.smoothScrollToPosition(0); for moving listview back top position 0 ??

Comment: I have abbadonded this problem. Now I am using scroll to refresh library, and it has its own listview

Comment: Thanks for your reply can i have link for that library pleaase ??

Comment: of course https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
lstView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

or

```
lstView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
ListView().scrollBy(x, y). I'm not sure

Comment: I have tryed that, when deltaY == 0 , but it start jumping upward and then it restores its place at the middle